# Does the order of declaring parameters for getaddrinfo matter?

Tags: c, getaddrinfo

I am writing a small server-client program using `getaddrinfo()`.

while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mswsock.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

char port[] = "1933";
char ip[]  = "192.168.178.26";

int main() {
    // Prolog - init socket
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        printf("- ERROR : WSAStartup() : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    int status;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct addrinfo *res = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *p = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    status = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, &res);

    for ( p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next ) {
    printf("Before calling socket:\n\tres\t= %p\n\tp\t= %p\n", res, p);

        // check all returned entries
        if ( (sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1 ) {
            printf("- ERROR : socket() : ",
            WSAGetLastError());
            continue; }

    printf("After calling socket:\n\tres\t= %p\n\tp\t= %p\n", res, p);

        if ( connect(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1 ) {
            printf("- ERROR : connect() : ",
            WSAGetLastError());
            continue; }

        // socket was successfully connected
        else {
    printf("After calling connect:\n\tres\t= %p\n\tp\t= %p\n", res, p);
            printf("+ SUCCESS : socket connected\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return sock; }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    printf("- ERROR : socket could not be connected\n");
    return 0;
}
```

works fine, changing the position of `struct addrinfo hints;` to

```
int status;
SOCKET sock;
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *res = NULL;
struct addrinfo *p = NULL;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
```

will lead to **unexpected behavior** after creating the socket. In detail the `*res`is then randomly changed after the first call of `socket()`.

I am coding with **Codeblocks** and a **GNU GCC Compiler**.

Output of the *version1* (working):

```
Before calling socket:
    res = 0049FBC8
    p   = 0049FBC8
After calling socket:
    res = 0049FBC8
    p   = 0049FBC8
After calling connect:
    res = 0049FBC8
    p   = 0049FBC8
+ SUCCESS : socket connected
```

Output of *version2* (not working):

```
Before calling socket:
    res = 007DFBC8
    p   = 007DFBC8
After calling socket:
    res = 00000002
    p   = 007DFBC8
After calling connect:
    res = 0000007C
    p   = 007DFBC8
+ SUCCESS : socket connected
```

Comment: The arguments in the parameter list just need to be created and initialized, such that they contain the correct data type/value.  The function will read them (or update them) per its implementation.  It does not matter the order the values were set, as long as they were set before using them in the parameter list.

Comment: The mentioned change should make no difference and therefore smells like UB. I think you need to post complete examples of both situations.

Comment: @ryyker thanks for that fast answer. So I assume it is a **Codeblocks Bug?**

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE.  What compiler are you using?  That is more likely where the problem exists.

Comment: *So I assume it is a Codeblocks Bug?*  ?!?!?!  How about checking for bugs and undefined behavior in the rest of your code?

Comment: Should `status = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, &res);` be changed to `status = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, res);`?  (i.e. `res` is already a pointer)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, try again, and see what you get.

Comment: @ryyker I am using **mingw32-gcc.exe** but having a **64-bit VM**.

Comment: Changing to `struct addrinfo res = NULL;` is not permitted: _incompatible types when assigning to 'struct addrinfo *' from type 'struct addrinfo'_

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Yes, agreed, looked it up as you commented, thanks, deleted comment.

Comment: Did you check the return value of getaddrinfo (status)?

Comment: I have seen the `memset` command used as `memset((void*)&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));` when clearing `hints`.  I am not sure this would fix anything though.

Comment: @king_nak yes, the return value is `0`. Also the connection is set up (I receive a _accept_ on server side). But because of the randomly changing `*res`I get a _segmentation fault_ after calling `freeaddrinfo(res)`

Comment: Supposing that `memset()` has an in-scope prototype, it is not necessary to cast its first argument from a different pointer type to type `void *`.  This happens implicitly as part of the function call.

Comment: @Stargateur **it is** the true OP running exactly like this in a separated project in codeblocks. It was before designed as a `getSocket()`function and for debugging I separated this part to a single project. Thats where the relict `return sock` comes from.

Comment: @hurm, *how do you know* that the address data is being changed?  I don't see anything in your code that would reveal that directly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger because I watched it in debugger: https://streamable.com/oqd3l

Comment: The thing is, @hurm, I don't see anything that would explain the behavior you describe.  I certainly could be missing something, but it would be easier to reason about the behavior (and it would prove that it matters) if the changes you describe could be made to have an externally observable effect.  For example, perhaps you could update the code to print out the original and modified data, and present the resulting output of both variations of the program.

Comment: Thanks, @hurm, but are those *really* the `printf()` statements that produced the output you added?  The pointer arguments whose values you are printing appear to be missing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes you were right. I updated it manually because for getting SC from the VM  I need a USB. No it should be ok.

Comment: Ok, that's already helpful.  When you said `*res` was modified, I took you literally, as meaning that the data to which `res` points is modified.  It appears that what is really happening is that `res` itself (the pointer) is modified.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry for not being specific enough. 
I tried the following:
```....
structaddrinfo hints;
int test = 123;
...```
That made the program working again! I expected that maybe the value of the `int test`could be changed(as it is now the one behind `hints`, but it isn't.

Comment: I have studied it, but I don't see any problems with the code.  My best guess is that there is some kind of mismatch, likely involving the definition of type `SOCKET`.  That is, maybe your Winsock headers are mismatched with the Winsock library you're actually linking.  That's speculative, but such a problem could explain stack corruption in the vicinity of `sock`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for expending your time. I will just accept it as it is and try not to think about the hours I spend investigating this failure :-)
Thanks for helping!